# Difference in NSDateFormatter between iPad simulator and device

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdateformatter

i'm using the following code to parse a date string:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE',' dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
NSDate *lastUpdate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Fri, 16 Sep 2011 11:11:35 GMT"];
[dateFormatter release];
```

it works prefectly in the simulator but when i set a breakpoint and look at the value for lastUpdate on an actual device, i see an "invalid CFStringRef" there instead of the correct date like in the simulator.

what am i missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the locale on the device the same as the simulator? You may need to force a US locale on the date formatter

Comment: Worked for me. My locale was es_MX and the simulator had en_US.